# Fetching explorer data from FlurryAPI

Tags: analytics, yahoo, flurry, flurry-analytics

Can we fetch data from the Explorer tool with FlurryAPI? If not, Are there any different methods to get the data from there?

Answer (score 0):

Flurry Explorer data can be exported in csv form, but can not currently be gathered via API.